# label = tkinter.label(mainWindow, text='hello world')

Tags: tkinter, module, label, attributeerror

I use IntelliJ and when I run my program I take attribute error I see Tkinter module has no attribute label my file name is t1.

```
Try:
    import tkinter
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tkinter

mainWindow = tkinter.Tk()

mainWindow.title("hello world")
mainWindow.geometry('640x480+8+400')

label = tkinter.label(mainWindow, text='hello world')
label.pack(side='left')

canvas = tkinter.canvas(mainWindow, relif='raised', borderwidth=1)
canvas.pack(side='right')

mainWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: i use intellij when i run my program i take attribute error i see tkinter module has no attrbiute label my file name is t1

Comment: Edit your code so it will have proper indentation and ask your question, I don't understand what is your problem.

Comment: tkinter widget class name should start with capital letter, so `tkinter.label(...)` should be `tkinter.Label(...)`. Same for `tkinter.canvas(...)`.

Comment: Stackoverflow is useful because it is user friendly - your question is not. Please edit your question as follows:
1) Change the title to a question in English eg. Please help me understand why IntelliJ says "module has no attribute label" 
2) Play with Stackoverflow's markdown so that it's clear what is code. We do love the fact that the whole question is just code, but it is also important for you to be a good commnuicator if you want to become a good programmer, especially if you want to work in larger teams some day, and build much bigger projects. Never too early to start practicing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change `label = tkinter.label(mainWindow, text='hello world')` to:

```
l = tkinter.Label(mainWindow, text='hello world')
```

"label" should start with capital letter (Label) as it is a convention used for naming classes

Same applies for your "canvas" too:

```
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(mainWindow, relief='raised', borderwidth=1)
```

It is suggested to not use same name for variable and classes as somewhere it can produce an error, so use `l` variable for `Label` and `c` variable for `Canvas`.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Actually OP wants the import compatible to both Python 2 and 3, so the line should be `import Tkinter as tkinter`.